# Why doesn't my die() text get displayed?

Tags: php, mysql, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

This is my first web programming project for years so please forgive me if the question is really basic. Here's my code

```
<?php
require_once('base.php');

//connect to DB
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, 'wrong password') 
     or die ("Unable to establish connection to MySQL: " + mysql_error($conn));
?>
```

The base.php defines the variables `$dbhost` and `$dbuser`. As you can see, I intentionally used a wrong password for DB connection. When I open the page in a browser, I expect to see the text `"Unable to establish connection to MySQL: ... "`. However, what I see is:

[image]

When I change `die()` to `echo()`, nothing changes. What am I missing?
I am using Wamp.

Comment: In PHP, you concatenate strings with a `.`, not `+` (like in JavaScript). Which means, your code isn't syntactically correct and will not get executed.

Comment: The second warning in that list is actually happening within your die() call.

Comment: @AmalMurali clearly he HAS error reporting enabled.

Comment: @Jessica: Ah, right. He even posted the error in an image. I didn't see that. I updated my comment.

Comment: I wonder, since when are legitimate questions that have an obvious answer deemed off-topic in SO?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Read the flags. "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."

This is a simple typographical error. It's not going to be of use to others in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the wrong concatenation operator. `+` is for JavaScript. [In PHP we use `.`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

```
or die ("Unable to establish connection to MySQL: " + mysql_error($conn));
```

should be:

```
or die ("Unable to establish connection to MySQL: " . mysql_error($conn));
```

**edit**

To follow up on @MichaelBerkowski's and @Jessica's comments, you should see nothing as your output from `die()` since PHP will [type juggle](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) those two strings, type juggle them into zeros, and give you a sum of zero. [`die(0)` will then output nothing](http://codepad.viper-7.com/lDRuwg). This will change once you implement the solution mentioned above.

Comment: Somewhere in the output, there should be a `"0"` since 2 non-numeric strings are cast and add up to 0.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski die(0); will print nothing.

Comment: It's ironic that `die(0)` is supposed to mean the program exited successfully.